# Access Carbon datasource from master-datasources.xml

Tags: java, datasource, jndi, wso2

I wanted to create a database connection using the Carbon datasource in java app.
I'm getting the below exception

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc
>       at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:116)
>       at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:124)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at org.wso2.ApiInvocationHnadler.DBConnection.testJndiDataSource(DBConnection.java:77)
>       at org.wso2.ApiInvocationHnadler.ApiInvocationHandler.handleRequest(ApiInvocationHandler.java:35)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:284)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:83)
>       at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:64)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
>       at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRESTRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:558)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doNhttpREST(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:498)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doREST(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:317)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:210)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:77)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

here is the master-datasources.xml

> ```
> <datasource>
>             <name>test_db</name>
>             <description>The datasource used for </description>
>             <jndiConfig>
>                     <name>jdbc/test_db</name>
>             </jndiConfig>
>             <definition type="RDBMS">
>                     <configuration>
>                             <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?autoReconnect=true</url>
>                             <username>root</username>
>                             <password>root</password>
>                             <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
>                             <maxActive>50</maxActive>
>                             <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
>                             <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
>                             <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
>                             <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
>                     </configuration>
>             </definition>
>     </datasource>
> ```

Java Code

> ```
>       Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
>       env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
>       env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://localhost:2199");
>       InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
>       DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/test_db");
> ```

How do I over come this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to the tenant flow, have to get the super tenant flow and lookup for the datasource

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point a code that is used by me to create that data source. You can find it from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/xacml/pip/jdbc/src/main/org/xacmlinfo/xacml/pip/jdbc/KMarketJDBCAttributeFinder.java). Just create the `InitialContext` with default constructor and it works for me to load the datasource from `master-datasources.xml` file.

> dataSource = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup(dataSourceName);`

Comment: I tried that way also but its not working, is there any configuration I have to add or set environment?  How is this connect with master-datasources.xml ? I'm using a wos2 product and adding the jar file in to lib folder, similar to your post http://xacmlinfo.org/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/

Comment: Do I have to add properties in the datasources.properties file ?

Comment: Nope. I just did the step in the blog.. It normally should works.  Just change the  ctx.lookup("jdbc/test_db"); in to some other datasource in master-datasources.xml file and see...  whether this error is generating

Comment: yeah it gives the error to other one also javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/WSO2AM_DB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].